# JPA - Best practises with queries

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a project with JPA and I am trying to keep my queries in proper order. So I have @Entity with

```
@NamedQuery(name = Entity.FIND_BY_NAME, query = "SELECT p FROM Entity p")
```

and inside entity

```
public static final String FIND_BY_NAME = "Entity.findByName";
```

and next I have an interface repository with

```
List<Entity> findByName();
```

So is there any way to call this query directly? Any annotation which can I use in repository interface?
On the other hand, if there is wrong in my code, please avice me what can I improve.

Comment: For one thing, a method named findByName() should find by name. Not return all instances, whatever their name. Have you read the documentation of spring-data-jpa? https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.named-queries, https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html#name--

Comment: Sure, agreed. It was only example, I know it was incorrect.